# share a location with other apps in react native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to share a longitude and latitude location with other apps like Google maps?

I know how to share a text but a location is my problem.

```
Share.share({
        message: 'message text body',
        title: 'title',
        url: 'http://site.ir'
    })
        .then(this._showResult)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to open google maps on a custom location from your app?

Comment: my need is custom direction between two location